# How to write an array of bytes in zip and then read it from there

Tags: java, arrays, zip

Sorry for my English.
I need zzat array of bytes (I do it through zip), but I do not use files, channels and buffers.
After that I need to unload (unzip this array to another array)
I did something like this but it doesn't work:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] b = "Help me please".getBytes();               
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();     
        try {
            baos.write(b);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try (ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos)){
            ZipEntry out = new ZipEntry("1");
            zos.putNextEntry(out);

            zos.closeEntry();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        byte[] a = baos.toByteArray();                               //compressed array

        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(a);
        try(ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(bais)){
                System.out.println('1');
                byte[]c = zis.readAllBytes();
                zis.closeEntry();
                System.out.println(c.equals(b));
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the purpose is of your first write to baos: `baos.write(b);`

Comment: I think after `putEntry()` you forgot to write the bytes for the entry itself: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html#write-byte%3AA-int-int-

Comment: With this command, I wanted to put the array in ByteraArayStream and then transfer this stream to zip
I can also use
write(b,0,b.length)
But it does not help

Comment: But you did that *before you had opened a Zip file stream.* It's weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me.  Note that I *open the Zip file stream first,* then I open the entry, then I write the bytes.  It has to go in that order or it doesn't work.

```
public class ZipFileTest {

   public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException {
      byte[] b = "Help me please".getBytes( "UTF-8" );
      ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      try( ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream( baos ) ) {
         ZipEntry out = new ZipEntry( "1 First" );
         zos.putNextEntry( out );
         zos.write( b, 0, b.length );
         zos.closeEntry();
      }

      byte[] a = baos.toByteArray();        //compressed array
      ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream( a );

      try( ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream( bais ) ) {
         for( ZipEntry zipe; (zipe = zis.getNextEntry()) != null; ) {
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            int length = zis.read( data, 0, data.length );
            System.out.println( "Entry: " + zipe.toString() );
            System.out.println( "Data: " + new String( data, 0, length, "UTF-8" ) );
            zis.closeEntry();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Output:

```
run:
Entry: 1 First
Data: Help me please
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: I figured out my errors and corrected your code a bit.
thanks for the help
But why after the operation data.equals(a) ,возвращается false ?